# Fixing all references with NuGet and TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

A coworker and I use TFS for managing several web projects in Visual Studio 2015. I just spent the last four hours or so fixing all of the references on my machine from his check-in, and we have problems like this (though to a lesser degree) each time we need to pull from the other's edits. NuGet doesn't get packages like it's supposed to (Package Restore is **enabled**), and most of the time we end up with the standard errors of VS either being unable to find an assembly or mismatching assembly versions.

What is the proper way to handle this situation so our references and packages stay synchronized across our machines?

Comment: When you say "package restore is enabled", do you mean old-style package restore with a `.nuget/NuGet.targets` folder? If so, that's been deprecated for a long time and is very likely a major source of your problems.

Comment: We always just do a 'Clean' and then 'Rebuild' and the package manager fixes all the discrepancies.  You are saying that is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use packed manager console. And install missing packed in pm console. Be sure all tfs project members using same version of packed assemblies.